# ButtonBase.IsPressed is inaccessible in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I tried to changed size of button when I press button, and I used "Click" and "MouseLeave" events, but I don't want button's size change without pressing button. I was using ButtonBase.Ispressed to make this function, but I got an error says: ButtonBase.IsPressed can't be used, because the set accessor is inaccessible. Please help me to access to this set accessor. Thanks.
Here is code:

```
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }



    private void SearchMedicationButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        double _width = 436;
        double _height = 593;

        DoubleAnimation widthAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(_width,_width*0.8,new Duration(timeSpan:TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.2)));
        DoubleAnimation heightAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(_height,_height*0.8,new Duration(timeSpan:TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.2)));

        SearchMedicationButton.BeginAnimation(Button.WidthProperty, widthAnimation);
        SearchMedicationButton.BeginAnimation(Button.HeightProperty,heightAnimation);
    }

    private void SearchMedicationButton_OnMouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        double _width = 436;
        double _height = 593;

        DoubleAnimation widthAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(_width*0.8, _width , new Duration(timeSpan: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.2)));
        DoubleAnimation heightAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(_height*0.8, _height, new Duration(timeSpan: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.2)));

        SearchMedicationButton.BeginAnimation(Button.WidthProperty, widthAnimation);
        SearchMedicationButton.BeginAnimation(Button.HeightProperty, heightAnimation);
    }
```

Comment: Did you post correct snippet of code? I found neither `Ispressed` nor `ButtonBase`.

Comment: `ButtonBase.IsPressed can't be used, because the set accessor is inaccessible` the error is clear. Post the *relevant* code - perhaps you typed `if (btn.IsPressed = true)` instead of `if (btn.IsPressed == true)` or `if (btn.IsPressed)` ?

Comment: HI, Panagiotis, you're right, that's wise! thank you

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you're looking for something like bellow -

[image]

Following is the correct way to do it...

XAML UI

```
<Button x:Name="Helllll" 
            Content="Hello" 
            Height="30" Width="60"/>
```

C# code for MainWindow

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;

            Helllll.MouseEnter += new MouseEventHandler(Helllll_MouseEnter);
            Helllll.MouseLeave += new MouseEventHandler(Helllll_MouseLeave);
        }

        void Helllll_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Helllll.Height = 30;
            Helllll.Width = 60;
        }

        void Helllll_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Helllll.Height = 60;
            Helllll.Width = 100;
        }
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: That's what the OP's code already does. The question is how to change size only when the button is pressed. The code doesn't match the question either

Comment: Thanks a lots, Dileepa, I also found if I remove "toValue: _width" in MouseLeave event, it works fine, I don't know why...